# how can i set frequencies of outcomes of rand() functon in c

Tags: c, random

i need to write a program to simulate rolling of two dice and store their sum in an array. it is given that frequency of sum=2&12 should be minimum and frequency of sum=7 is maximum.
this is the code i've written. i need random numbers between 2 and 12 with said frequencies

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main()
{
   int i, n;


   n = 5;
          srand ( time(NULL) );


   for( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) 
   {

      printf("%d\n", rand() % 12);
   }

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to just call rand()%6+1 twice and sum the results? You'd be simulating the exact same behavior with much simpler math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `rand()` to generate a number for each of the 36 pairs, then return the sum.

```
int dice2sum(void) {
  int r = rand()%36;
  int die1 = r%6 + 1;
  int die2 = r/6 + 1;
  return die1 + die2;
}
```